# Signing WLMA.ocx with ev signing code certificate

Tags: code-signing, playready

In order to get Microsoft PlayReady Server Agreement I need to sign WMLA.ocx file with Extended Validation Code Signing Certificate and send it back to Microsoft.
I've obtained Extended Validation Code Signing Certificate pack from Thawte, it contains:
1. Code Signing certificate itself
2. CA
3. PKCS7 certificate

Put Code Signing certificate itself to separate file with .cer extension.

I've downloaded Microsoft Code Signing pack from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=148072 contains:
a. Signcode.exe
b. WMLA.ocx
c. WMLA Instructions for EV Cert OCX v10 17 16.pdf

Following instructions (option 3) from http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537364.aspx we've tried to sign .ocx file using Signcode.exe and Code Signing certificate itself in .cer file.
Enter following command in command line:

```
C:\Users\User123\WMLA>signcode.exe -c ev.cer WMLA.ocx
```

And got error:

```
Error: There is no valid certificate in the my cert store
Error: Signing Failed.  Result = 8009200c, (-2146885620)
```

Certificate is valid, but I'm not sure about signcode.exe options and putting certificate in separate .cer file?